# Azure AD OAuth Client Credentials Grant flow

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Trying to set up Azure AD OAuth client credentials grant flow for my web api. I'm following the document in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow. I have to expose my API to a 3rd party. I've created the APP in Azure AD (this is for the client that is requesting my API), generated the secrets and was able to get a response from oauth2/token endpoint. My questions are below:

1. What is the best way to validate the token? Is it by passing the JWT
       (bearer token) as a HTTP header to my API, and then using the SDK to
       validate the token
       (System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler)? I'm using
       C#.
2. What is the significance of Azure AD -> App Registrations -> "My
       API App" -> under Manage, Expose an API? It has an option to
       "Authorize client applications". How could I use this feature to
       conditionally block and approve the client applications?
3. I will have to share the secret, client id and the App Id Uri with the 3rd party for them to generate the token and I will validate the token when I receive it.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

This answer, [Azure AD OAuth client credentials grant flow with Web API AuthorizeAttribute Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397552/azure-ad-oauth-client-credentials-grant-flow-with-web-api-authorizeattribute-rol), will walk you through one way to do this, using the `roles` claim in the token to authorize the call.

You will need to:

- define roles
- create an *App registration* for each 3rd party
- assign their application to your desired roles

You can then use the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute) to map which roles can execute which controllers/actions, like so:

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Reader,Requester,Editor,Approver,Administrator")]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Token validation**

Once you complete token obtaining flow, you receive a JWT bearer access token. From token consuming end (your service), you need to perform a JWT validation. This is done by validating JWT signature and Claims. One of the most important claim you validate is the audience (***aud***) claim which must be the identifier (ex:- your service's URL, an ID) unique to token receiving service. Where you register this ? That's your second question.

Please read through MS's guide on token validation which explains key points - [Microsoft identity platform access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)

2. **Service registration**

This is where you register valid token receivable endpoints (ex:- your api app). If you check your token request, you provide ***resource*** parameter which must match to registered identifier. This allows Azure to validate the token request and issue an access token the mentioned resource. You find this as ***aud*** claim in the token. Hope you got the connection now.

3. **App secret**

No, only the token obtaining party require the client credentials. Your API or any token consuming party does not need the secret. They only require a valid access token and token signing certificate details. certificate details are exposed at ***jwks_uri*** in ***openid-configuration*** endpoint.

Comment: Can you provide more details (example) for point 2 (service registration) I don't understand how to use the _Authorize client applications_ field, here I must insert a clientId but wich ?

Comment: I checked the document. It says following "Enter the App ID URI of the receiving web service. To find the App ID URI, in the Azure portal, click Azure Active Directory, click App registrations, click the service application, and then click Settings and Properties." You have to register your token receiving api to Azure (this makes sense.!). Then you get an AppID . Unfortunately I haven't done this personally.

Comment: @Max Some explanation on the registration. Basically you want to receive tokens  that are consumed by a known service. For Azure to issue such token, it must fist know such a service (ex:- API). Otherwise there's no way to set appropriate sub claim in JWT. Hope you got hold of the concept.

Comment: Even if I do not do an "Expose an API" and add a client id to  "Authorize Client Application", the token requesting app can still send the resource id in the token request  and get a token, which will be validated by my API that will consume the token. Since this is the case, what is the impact of using "Expose an API"?

Comment: @Thomas I do not think you can simply send a random value to resource parameter. Azure should perform a validation of it to be known. Impact of this is on security. You need to create a trust boundary among API, Azure (token issuer) and API consumer. Token issuer must know whom to it issue tokens.

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa The resource parameter will not be a random value - it will be app ID URI of the AAD application registered which corresponds to my API. The point I'm trying to make is, I can set App ID URI for my API, without having to  do an "Expose an API"  in the AAD that corresponds to my client app. I tried that, and it was working. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Thomas it depends on your design. If both API and Client APP belongs to you (same domain, same development) then it is fine. The token you receive will have mentioned ID as subject claim, which you must use for token validation. But if it is not the scenario, then you need to register both.

Comment: @Thomas All this is done to obtain tokens with restricted scope. The aud value restricts token to an audience. If you do not respect this, then a stolen token can be used to cause damage for all valid targets.