# Azure requires Scope in client credentials grant

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have 2 registered apps in Azure AD - one is a webapi that receives a webhook from SendGrid with an access token.  The other is the registration of the SendGrid app so that it can request a token using Client Credentials grant.  Admin consent has been granted for the exposed API to the SendGrid app registration.

In SendGrid's webhook configuration on their server (the service is in beta), we are asked for client_id, client_secret and token endpoint.  We also configure the web api resource url that it will eventually send the token and its webhook data.

In Azure identity platform, Scope is required but in the RFC it is optional.  SendGrid does not configure nor send the scope.  So these implementations appear not to be able to work together.

2 questions:

- If you do not send a scope to some other RFC compliant token endpoint, presume this means the requester can be authorized but the jwt has nothing for audience?
- If according to the RFC scope is not required, can the resource server check "this was meant for me"?

I understand we can validate the issuer and any extra claims but it seems odd that one of the validations that is emphasized most in Azure AD, Auth0 documentation etc is "audience" yet the RFC allows the scope to be missing in the token request.  One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57190250/azure-ad-oauth-client-credentials-grant-flow) again emphasizes this requirement.

I wondered if a scope could be configured in the client app registration manifest if it is missing in the request but could not find anything that looks like that.

Thanks in advance for insights.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your issue, but have you tried on the app registration with the expose an api configured, under it there is a authorized client applications section, try adding the other app registration id in there. I have anecdotally seen that even without requesting the scope, it will return that scope in the token.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @MarkD Did you resolve this issue? How did you do it?

Comment: Other priorities got in the way so we dropped this for now.  I'll see if I can test over the weekend - the registration is still configured so I should be able to set it up as alphaz18 suggested.  Can't promise a timescale - we have a lot on right now...